# How can we run multiple CLI command in Azure Bash together?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I have Multiple Resources to deploy in my Environment using CLI command all together. For Example: I need to create VM, Web App, Redis Cache, etc using a single script.
Instead of creating individual resources can we create all together.

Comment: Based on your requirements, I would actually recommend making use of ARM Templates and create all resources using a single template.

Comment: You just need to put all your CLI commands that you used to create the resources inside a single shell script and execute it. But first, you need to log in for the CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to put all your commands in a `.sh` shell script. Below is an example of how you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

az group create -n MyResourceGroup -l centralus

az vm create -n MyVm -g MyResourceGroup --image UbuntuLTS

az webapp create -g MyResourceGroup -p MyPlan -n MyUniqueAppName

# More Azure CLI commands to create resources
```

Then you can run your script inside your local environment bash shell or [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) like this:

```
username@Azure:~$ ./script.sh
```

Another way is to use an [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview) to deploy your resources.